# How can I pass a value into a variadic template function that forwards the value into a function that receives the value by copy?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have this scenario:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void printStringsAndID(const int id, const std::string& value1, const std::string& value2) {
    std::cout << id << ": " << value1 << ", " << value2 << '\n';
}

void printIntegerAndID(const int id, const int value) {
    std::cout << id << ": " << value << '\n';
}

template<typename... Args>
void callWithID(void(&function)(int, Args...), Args&&... args) {
    static int id{ 0 };
    ++id;
    function(id, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

void printStrings(const std::string& value1, const std::string& value2) {
    callWithID(printStringsAndID, value1, value2);
}

void printInteger(const int value) {
    callWithID(printIntegerAndID, value);
}

int main() {
    printStrings("Hello", "World");
    printInteger(42);
}
```

This will not compile.

If I make the function `printIntegerAndID` receive a const reference of a value it will compile. Suppose I can not change that function signature.

If I do not pass by RValue into the function `callWithID`, then the problem then shifts over to the strings. And suppose I am using a more complicated class like smart pointers then more issues arrive.

I could have another `callWithID` function, but then I can not mix values, and it adds code repeatition.

I find RValues complicated, I do not know much about them despite trying to. I do use smart pointers a lot, and I do store and forward functions a lot, and I combine both together, so this is the one scenario in which I feel like I need to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue with

```
template<typename... Args>
void callWithID(void(&function)(int, Args...), Args&&... args) {
    static int id{ 0 };
    ++id;
    function(id, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

is that `Args` is deduced from two places (and they should not conflict).

Possible solution is to use two template parameters:

```
template <typename... Ts, typename... Args>
void callWithID(void(&function)(int, Ts...), Args&&... args) {
    static int id{ 0 };
    ++id;
    function(id, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64c96b6afb2612ba)

Comment: You could also simply use a `template <typename F, typename... Args> void callWithID(F f, Args&&... args)`.

Comment: Both those do indeed work for the situation I provided. I did not know that the types conflicted, so thank you for that information. Is it safe to call the function if the types conflict? What is the conflict (I assume it is some rvalue lvalue stuff?)